# Scala map to HashMap

Tags: scala, collections, dictionary

Given a `List` of `Person` objects of this class:

`class Person(val id : Long, val name : String)`

What would be the "scala way" of obtaining a (java) HashMap with `id` for keys and `name` for values?

If the best answer does not include using `.map`, please provide an example with it, even if it's harder to do.

Thank you.

### EDIT

This is what I have right now, but it's not too immutable:

```
val map = new HashMap[Long, String]
personList.foreach { p => map.put(p.getId, p.getName) }

return map
```

Comment: Your current version is quite all right but if you need to convert between scala and java collections often, take a look at `scala.collections.JavaConverters` or `scala.collections.JavaConversions`.

Comment: How about this: (1) preallocate enough entries in the empty HashMap using personList's size, and (2) `return java.collections.unmodifiableMap(map)`? Mutable state is OK when it's confined to one local object — no side effects anyway :)

Comment: If that's the preferred way, please write an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I can barely read Scala, so I'm not sure that this is the preferred way. It should work, though; lets's see what commenters say.

Comment: @mpartel - just a heads-up: I converted your answer into a comment, as while it *is* useful information, it does not appear to actually answer the question.

Answer (score 11):

```
import collection.JavaConverters._
val map = personList.map(p => (p.id, p.name)).toMap.asJava
```

- `personList` has type `List[Person]`.
- After `.map` operation, you get `List[Tuple2[Long, String]]` (usually written as, `List[(Long, String)]`).
- After `.toMap`, you get `Map[Long, String]`.
- And `.asJava`, as name suggests, converts it to a Java map.

You don't need to define `.getName`, `.getid`. `.name` and `.id` are already getter methods. The value-access like look is intentional, and follows uniform access principle.

Comment: You may also encounter the `->` method used to create the tuple like so: `personList.map(p => (p.id -> p.name))`. This is very common in scala documentation. In rare cases, this causes type inference problems though and you must either supply explicit types or fall back to the standard tuple syntax.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

- preallocate enough entries in the empty `HashMap` using `personList`'s size,
- run the `foreach` loop,
- if you need immutability, `return java.collections.unmodifiableMap(map)`?

This approach creates no intermediate objects. Mutable state is OK when it's confined to one local object — no side effects anyway :)

Disclaimer: I know very little Scala, so be cautious upvoting this.